# Windows shortcut parameters for running with a folder

Tags: windows, command, shortcut

I have a `a.lnk` that is shortcut of `a.exe` and `b` folder in the same directory. I run the content of the `b` folder dragging and dropping it on `a.lnk`.

What parameters should I add to end of *target* property of the short cut to run it with the folder directly.

Comment: uh, you should add one parameter, which should be the folder name.

Comment: now I have it like "C:\Program Files\folder\a.exe" b
but it did not work, also tried b with quotes and dash front of it

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Start In:" folder to `""C:\Program Files\folder"` and then using `"C:\Program Files\folder\a.exe" b` ?  Have you tried `"C:\Program Files\folder\a.exe" "C:\Program Files\folder\b"` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikeNakis, second solution, writing the folders dir in double quotes worked.